# Redirection based on another site's cookies?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cookies, referrer

I'm looking for something to add to my .htaccess that will redirect any incoming traffic that has a cookie set by another website.

For example, if I have a website called DogsPaws.com and someone visits DogsNose.com (which sets a cookie), I want to redirect the incoming traffic I am receiving from DogsNose.com to a specific welcome page.

If I have a link on the DogsNose.com page, I can redirect based on a Referrer rule, but what happens if the person visits DogsNose.com and then closes out their browser and comes back the next day and types DogsPaws.com directly in their browser, I still want my redirection rule to apply.  I know that cookies expire and people clear them occasionally but for the most part, if the cookie is there, I want to redirect.  Is there any clear way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read cookies from other websites. The client doesn't send them.

There isn't any solution with .htaccess and if DogsNose.com doesn't belong to you there aren't any solutions at all.

Comment: Well that sucks.  Any other options?  How does google know what kind of ads to feed you?  If you search for dog food all the time, they start showing ads for dog food and other dog items.

Comment: @Rodeo: Actually you search them with google, not with another site.